# XML sorted list of only certain nodes

Tags: sorting

I have the following XML file. I need to print a list of only selected nodes (Total) in ascending order. I tried to use *sort* function, but there were some mistakes I couldn't identify and it returned everything, including values of other nodes in the initial file.
XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice>
    <From>
        <Name>Lucy</Name>
        <Country>UK</Country>
    </From>
    <To>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <Country>US</Country>
    </To>
    <Items>
        <Position>
            <Name>Table</Name>
            <Total>1</Total>
        </Position>
        <Position>
            <Name>Chair</Nr>
            <Total>4</Total>
        </Position>
        <Position>
            <Name>Cup</Name>
            <Total>5</Total>
        </Position>
        <Position>
            <Name>Box</Name>
            <Total>4</Total>
        </Position>     
    </Items>
</Invoice>
```

How could I get the required output using? 
Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us your attempted XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious approach to generate the desired output from the given input would be using an `xsl:for-each` also making use of `xsl:sort`:

```
<xsl:template match="/Invoice">
    <SortedTotalList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <xsl:for-each select="Positions/Position">
        <xsl:sort select="Total"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Total" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </SortedTotalList>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SortedTotalList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Total>1</Total>
    <Total>4</Total>
    <Total>4</Total>
    <Total>5</Total>
</SortedTotalList>
```